# Populating a card from and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was wondering whats the best way to populate a card I've created by selecting a name from a list that has used an ng-repeat. For example the array the ng-repeat is using contains items like this: `firstname: 'Ryan', secondname: 'Garrett', age: 23`. The ng-repeat only pulls the firstname, I want to be able to click the name and populate the card with the other details. What is the best way to do this? I have created a JSFiddle to help with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/2805/. Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<h3>People:</h3>
<br>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in items">{{x.firstname}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>

<div>
Persons name:
<br>Secound name:
<br>Age:
</div>
```

JS:

```
var m = [
    {firstname: 'Ryan', secondname: 'Garrett', age: 23},
    {firstname: 'Bob', secondname: 'Coolio', age: 56},
    {firstname: 'Clint', secondname: 'Eastwood', age: 34},
    {firstname: 'Scott', secondname: 'Eastwood', age: 45},
    {firstname: 'Stan', secondname: 'Lee', age: 59},
 ];

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = m;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the index of repeated items to function called with ng-click, and use that index to assign values from array to scope.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = m;
    $scope.getDetails = function(index) {
        $scope.details = $scope.items[index]
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    Persons name:{{details.firstname}}
    <br>Secound name:{{details.secondname}}
    <br>Age:{{details.age}}
</div>
```

Updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/2808/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `selectedItem` property in your controller.
Let's have a look:

**controller**

```
$scope.selectedItem;
```

**template**

- `ng-click` for selecting the current object
- binding the controller `selectedItem` to the card

  ```
  <h3>People:</h3>
  <br>
  <div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in items" ng-click='selectedItem = x'>{{x.firstname}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div>
  Persons name: {{selectedItem.firstName}}
  <br>Secound name: {{selectedItem.secondname}}
  <br>Age: {{selectedItem.age}}
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ng-click="fillCard(x)"` to your `<li>` and create a function in scope like

```
$scope.fillCard = function(item) {
  $scope.firstname = item.firstname;
  $scope.secondname = item.secondname;
}
```

And in html:

```
Persons name: {{firstname}}
<br>Secound name: {{secondname}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-click` and pass the clicked item

```
<li ng-repeat="x in items" ng-click="itemClicked(x)">{{x.firstname}}</li>
```

then in controller:

```
$scope.itemClicked = function(item){
                           $scope.selectedItem = item;
                     }
```

and in the UI template

```
<div>
Persons name: {{selectedItem.firstname}}
<br>Secound name: {{selectedItem.secondname}}
<br>Age: {{selectedItem.age}}
</div>
```